# EXE-ifying custom levels/scripts/graphics/music

Tags: c++, data, user-generated-content

My game is pretty much just a game-builder, where you create your own levels, scripts, graphics, music etc. and the game just loads them from a file you tell it. But how would I make it so the user could generate an exe that would just load the game files and act like a standalone game but actually be made with the game-builder thing? I'm using C++.

Comment: You should read a few topics about the PE-file-format, you may be able to write arbitrary data to the resource-section and then read it from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward approach could be to produce a folder which contains always the same executable, copied, and different files next to it. The executable would look for data files relative to itself.

```
.../MyNewThing/
    MyNewThing.exe <-- renamed but identical
    resources/ <-- files with known names or name-patterns
    MyNewThing.data <-- alternatively
```

So, it's not a single self-contained file, but should be quite clear that you need to copy the whole folder.